# Angularjs - TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" when work with dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
 <select id="ddlPropertyName" ng-options="property.Name for property in allProperty" ng-model="property.Name"><option value="">-Select Name-</option>
                            </select>
```

If there `no value selected in dropdown` i'm getting below error :(
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

js code
    Name: $scope.property.Name.Name

> But I want if no value gets selected still I can check undefined or null so that my Json can set value and code execute without execption

Comment: Could you share us your json code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some other model variable instead of `property`. Here in the modified HTML I have used `selectedProperty`

```
<select id="ddlPropertyName" 
    ng-options="property.Name for property in allProperty" 
    ng-model="selectedProperty">
    <option value="">-Select Name-</option>
</select>
```

Note: You are using `label for value in array` in [ngOption](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) so `selectedProperty` will hold the `property` type

Comment: thanks but I'm unable to set this value dataObj like var DataObj={ Property: $scope.selectedProperty.Name} error is `"Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined"`

Comment: @Neo, You need to set property initially `$scope.selectedProperty = $scope.allProperty[0]`, Can you post, How and When you are using `$scope.selectedProperty`?

Answer (score 0):

Below Code Works For Me

```
  <select ng-model="qid">
            <option value="">--Select--</option>
     <option ng-repeat="p in pollquestions" value="{{p.QId}}">{{p.QText}}</option>
 </select>

 app.controller("optionsCntrl", function ($scope, angularService) {
//$scope.optionsCntrl = [{ QId: 1, QText: "What is this 1?" }];
var getData = angularService.getQuestion();
getData.then(function (ques) {
    $scope.pollquestions = ques.data;
}, function () {
    alert('Error in getting records');
});
$scope.AddUpdatePollQuestionOption = function () {
    var pollquestionanswer = {
        qid:$scope.qid,
        anstext: $scope.anstext,
        anscount: 1
    };
    var getData = angularService.addPollQuestionOptions(pollquestionanswer).success(deferred.resolve).error(deferred.reject);
    getData.then(function (msg) {
        alert(msg.data);
    }, function () {
        alert('Error in adding record');
    });
}
});
 public string AddPollQuestionOptions(PollQuestionAnswer pollQuestionAnswer)
    {
        if (pollQuestionAnswer != null)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(pollQuestionAnswer.qid)))
            {
                try
                {
                    using (DemoContext contextObj = new DemoContext())
                    {
                        contextObj.pollquestionanswer.Add(pollQuestionAnswer);
                        contextObj.SaveChanges();
                        return "Poll Question Answer Added";
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception objEx)
                {
                    return "Poll Question Not Found";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return "Invalid Request";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return "Invalid Record";
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs basically when the fields specified by you in the Column Definition doesn't have name or the same column has been put twice in the Column Definition. Search for the similar column and remove one with the same name that will solve this error.

Answer (score -1):

Just use below code in your controller

```
if($scope.property.Name !== null || $scope.property.Name !== undefined) {
    console.log('here');
}
```